# How does one swap two panes in Tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have two panes in horizontal split. I'd like to have the pane currently on the right to be on the left in the window. I'm not talking about moving the focus (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>). How do I achieve this?

'left pane' <--> 'right pane'

Answer (score 557, accepted):

The `swap-pane` command can do this for you. The <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> keys are bound to `swap-pane -U` and `swap-pane -D` in the default configuration.

So, to effect your desired change, you can probably use <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> when you are in the right pane (or <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> if you are in the left pane).

The `-U` and `-D` refer to “up” and “down” in the pane index order (“up” is the same direction that <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> moves across panes). You can see the pane indices with `display-panes` (<kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>, by default).

Comment: +1 for specifying `Prefix` instead of assuming everyone will use `Ctrl-b`

Comment: Agreed. It's even worse when people assume you're using `Ctrl-a`, since they're the people who know that the prefix can be changed to suit the user.

Comment: See @kay's response for more general use of `swap-pane` (and answer to question in title).

Answer (score 114):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> and keep holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while hitting <kbd>o</kbd>. This will rotate all existing panes around, so in your case it will swap the only two existing panes.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> rotates the opposite way (useful when you have more than two panes).

Comment: Yeah, we're on the same page.  But after the first 'o', which does cause a pane rotation, the next 'o' is sent to the underlying shell and processed by whatever app be there.   I'm thinking something fishy with my map, or maybe something that's dependent on tmux version.

Thanks for responding.

Comment: @Stabledog I'm on tmux 2.3 currently, but I think this has always worked for me... I can't really think of what could be the issue. Sounds strange that the `Ctrl+o` is being sent to the shell instead of to tmux, especially if this is not the case for repeatedly pressing `Ctrl+b` (or other tmux commands?).

Comment: Actually I think it is happening for all commands.  At least, I'm not aware of any case where I can do Ctrl+x, hit a key that's bound to some operation, and stay in "tmux keyboard" mode.  I just assumed that's by design.

Comment: @Stabledog Actually, I just noticed that the only other command where I can keep holding down control and repeat the other keys is `Ctrl+b;`, which keeps rotating the cursor between two panes.

Answer (score 77):

The most precise control you can have is by using the command `swap-pane` *directly*. This is not so difficult to do:

1. `ctrl-b q` shows you the "ID" for each pane in current window - remember the two panes you want to swap. Let's say they're 3 and 5.
2. `ctrl-b :` to activate the tmux command line. Then issue command `swap-pane -s3 -t5`.

Note that you have auto-completion when typing commands. Also you can search for syntax of a command directly from [tmux manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tmux/). That's how I learn the syntax for `swap-pane`.

Answer (score 18):

To directly swap two panes:

1. Select the first pane with <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd>
   (the default for <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd>)
2. Go to the second pane, and type <kbd>prefix</kbd> `:swap-pane`